# How to localize Developer Express VCL components at Design Time in Delphi 2006?

Tags: delphi, devexpress, vcl

I can only translate my application to my language using TcxLocalizer at runtime, but I need this working also in design-time.

Does anyone has some suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All constants necessary for localize DevExpress are implemented/included in source code of devexpress. I not remember the name of file, but included in source of DevExpress are some unit that containts all the values. If you translate this constants and rebuild the packages you obtain this components in other languages.

If you search in Google you can find some translations of this components.

Regards.

P.D: Excuse-me for mistakes with english.

Comment: OK. Thank you for the answer. By now I will let it in English because I saw that there is no advantage on having the components translated in design time. What worth is the runtime. Thank you.